# Default Argument in C++ have some special properties?

Tags: c++, function, arguments, heap-memory, default

This is an interview test question not homework. The test has been done.

Which of the following statements about default arguments in C++ are correct ?

```
A. Default Argument cannot be of a user-defined type.
B. Default Argument can never precede non-default arguments
C. Default Argument cannot be of pointer type.
D. Default Argument exist in global heap not function's stack
E. Default Argument are not considered for generating the function's signature.
```

I chose B and E. Are these correct?  I am not sure about D, is that correct too?

Comment: F - don't ever use default arguments

Comment: @JimRhodes: Care to explain that?

Comment: @NicolBolas: It was a joke but I never use them. I have seen them lead to mistakes. And if you are looking at code you are not familiar with you may not realize there are more parameters being passed to a function.

Comment: @Jim Rhodes: How would you better tackle a situation where you need to alter an existing function that's numerously called from various places, without touching those lines?

Comment: @AssafLevy: Change the existing function to call the new function.

Comment: @Jim Rhodes: but how would the existing function know *when* to call the new function?

Comment: @AssafLevy: The old function would always call the new function, passing reasonable defaults for the new arguments.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

B is true. A, C and D are false.

E requires clarification. It depends on what is meant by "generating the function's signature".

As far as the compiler is concerned, the signature is the signature. Default arguments only matter when *calling* the function. That's where the defaults are substituted in. So the function has the signature it is written with.

If "generating the function's signature" means "what is the C++ signature of the function is", then the signature doesn't care whether an argument is default. But if "generating the function's signature" means "how you call it", then it does care about the defaults.

Answer (score 2):

A, C, and D are all definitely false. B is definitely true. I'm not so sure about E, I always forget.